# ¿Como hacer que mis gráficos se vean completos al renderizarlo a formato word en R Markdown?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

Cuando renderizo mi script a word los gráficos que en la pantalla de visualización se veían completos se ven cortados.

En este ejemplo tanto el título del gráfico como el caption me salen cortados.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que esto no suceda?

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir un [mcve] ?

Comment: Ya lo solucioné, pero no sé cómo eliminar la pregunta

Comment: Debajo de la lista de etiquetas deberías tener algunos botones, entre ellos el eliminar